# How do I decode google travel (hotel) search url?

Tags: base64, decode, url-parameters

I want to put the check-in date and check-out date into the url to search by specifying the date. For example from this URL

```
https://www.google.com/travel/search?q=Nine%20Blue%20Residence&ved=0CAAQ5JsGahcKEwiwpPOT1-6CAxUAAAAAHQAAAAAQBQ&ts=CAAaGhIYEhIKBwjnDxAMGBQSBwjnDxAMGBUyAggCKgcKBToDVEhC&qs=MidDaGtJd3NPVndhT3E0TnduR2cwdlp5OHhNV2QwZUdOdU4yaGlFQUU
```

I'm trying to decode  ts, qs, ap, ved with base64 but can't decode.

I would like to know if there is another way to insert the check-in date into the url and when pressing the url, open the google travel page of the hotel that we entered in the parameters.

Comment: I think ts is the date, because I tested changing the stay date several times and noticed that ts changed.